# Why is https communication not working with iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables

I'm trying to configure iptables for security settings.

Basically, I set up a whitelist and tried to test it.

I set the following settings to allow ssh, http, and https to my server by allowing input values of 22, 80,443.
And temporary ports were also allowed.

```
​sudo iptables -t filter -F
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000: -j ACCEPT
```

The following is a list of settings.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:3000:65535
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I allowed it as above, but I was able to connect normally to ssh and apache on port 80 of my server.

However, the "curl https://google.com" command did not respond properly on my server.

The strange thing is after adding the following rule:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

When I do "curl https://google.com", communication is completed normally.

What is the reason for this and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have a rule to allow response packets from the internet to come through.

That is, DNS request is sent to an internet host at UDP port 53, and its reply comes from internet from UDP port to a random port that client used to make request.

Similarly, the TCP packets from internet are dropped, because there is no rule to allow packets from internet server port 443 to random client port.

You need to add the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This enables Netfilter connection tracking, that ensures that IP packets of a TCP connection / UDP association are properly allowed.

Comment: Thanks to this, I became familiar with iptables and routes. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The last iptables input rule is incorrectly formatted

And add some logging so you have more troubleshooting inf.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
```

You can also use log analyzers like logwatch, and iptables-log-parser to get more insights from the logs.